# Install Ubuntu on Yosemite

Tags: macos, install, unix

I created a bootable thumb drive using the instructions here: [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). I installed the 32bit and 64bit version.

I got a MacBook Pro (15" End 2011) Processor 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7 Storage 16 GB 1333 Mhz DDR3, Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB & AMD Radeon HD 6750M, 128 GB SSD

When I boot the Mac and press <kbd>alt</kbd> I can select the USB drive. Then it starts GRUB and I can select "Install Ubuntu".

Then black screen appears and the Ubuntu sound appears and then nothing happens.

What can I do?

Comment: Where did you look for the instructions ?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but I thought I'd boot it out there just in case. Assuming you have sufficient RAM (6 - 8GB) it might be easier to install Ubuntu (or any Linux dist.) in a virtual Machine. Parallels and VMWare Fusion are the two big commercial virtualization apps, but I have found that the free (and frequently updated) VirtualBox is easier than doing a dual boot system with the added benefits of it being quite easy to have both running at the same time.

As virtualbox is free you could try it and see if it suits your needs...

Comment: i tried virtual box it works good but the ubuntu is on full screen mode smaller then the display und has a big black border around the display how do i get rid of the border?

Comment: Not sure, you may need to ask that on the VirtualBox or Ubuntu forums...

Comment: Yes it works now but it is not what i am looking for i want a dual boot

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the Mac App Store option [Veertu](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/veertu/id1024069033?mt=12)

It's free at launch to run various linux OS and has a paid upgrade for ISO based install options.

The benefits of this over other virtualization options are that it runs within the OS X sandbox which makes it less likely to cause crashes and it lets OS X control the battery/power management.

Also, many pre-packaged linux installs are one click easy.